# helloworld CICS bundle example is disabled on install on region

Tags: osgi-bundle, cics

I am a student and work in a project on mainframe of my university . I try to create simple helloworld application from chapter 3 of [Java Application in CICS (SC34-7174-02)](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248038.html?Open) with CICSExplorer 5.2 for CICS 4.2 on Z OS 1.13.

in fact , i have CICS bundle project and two OSGI bundle (Hello and Web examples of CICSExplorer) that included on CICS Bundle .

I exported it to zFS and then created bundle , program , transaction  and CSD Group that included them to it .

I used a region that have installed JVMServer . then I run JHE1 transaction and saw console . JVM profile is DFHJVMCD .

I installed CSD Gorup on a region . bundles view of CICSExplorer shows my bundle and finds bundle parts but CICSBundle is disabled and bundle parts are unusable .

I search and find [CICS and the JVM server Developing and Deploying Java applications](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248038.html?Open) . in 2.4.2 header explained common problem for my CICSBundle State .

JVM server is discarded
JVM server is installed after the BUNDLE installation

neither of these not happened .
any help can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it . JVMServer was not installed .

Answer (score 1):

If the CICS bundle parts are UNUSABLE then one likely problem is that the region does not have the right access to the zFS where your bundle has been deployed. You can always check the MSGLOG. Please see "Giving CICS regions access to z/OS UNIX directories and files in the IBM Knowledge Center" (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSGMCP_5.2.0_beta/com.ibm.cics.ts.java.doc/topics/dfhpjd8.html).

Comment: i check permission of my CICSbundle directory and this was rwxr-x--- (750) . i set that to full access (777) and  but any change not happened . when i try to enable installed CICS Bundle on region . i get this error :  CNX0591E: EXEC CICS command(SET BUNDLE) RESP(INVREQ) RESP2(6) .

Answer (score 1):

There is often more useful information inside the MSGUSR logs of the CICS region. For example, if the JVM server is not present, it will tell you. If it cannot access the bundle directory (which seems to be a common error when using FTP to export bundles), it will tell you that it cannot access the META-INF folder, and so on.